# Add filename to a new column when using map_df in r

Tags: r, purrr

Is there a quick and easy way using dplyr to add a column called 'site_id' which populates rows from the number given to the filename when using map_df from purrr package to bring the data in to one dataframe?

For example **my.files** will read in two csv files:
"H:/Documents/2015.csv" and "H:/Documents/2021.csv"

```
my.files <- list.files(my.path, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

I then use map_df to bring all the data in to one data frame, but would like to create an additional column called 'site_id' that will populate each row from that file with its original file title e.g. 2015 or 2021

I currently merge the .csv files together with this code:

```
temp.df <- my.files %>% map_df(~read.csv(., skip = 15))
```

But I envisage using mutate to help but am unsure how it would work...

```
temp.df <- my.files %>% map_df(~read.csv(., skip = 15) %>%
 mutate(site_id = ????))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `imap` if we want to use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
setNames(my.files, my.files) %>%
   imap_df(~ read.csv(.x, skip = 15) %>%
             mutate(site_id = .y))
```

---

Or specify the `.id` in `map`

```
setNames(my.files, my.files) %>%
     map_dfr(read.csv, skip = 15, .id = "site_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr` & `dplyr`:

```
temp.df <- my.files %>%
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  purrr::map(., ~read.csv(., skip = 15)) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "site_id")
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the ` map_dfr()` here which basically combines `map` and `bind_rows` :)